# Postgres asterisc regex quantifier not working

Tags: regex, postgresql, quantifiers

In Postgres 9.5.1 the following command works:

```
select regexp_replace('JamesBond007','\d+','');
```

Output:

```
JamesBond
```

However the asterisc does not seem to work:

```
select regexp_replace('JamesBond007','\d*','');
```

it produces:

```
JamesBond007
```

Even more weird things happen when I put something in as replacement string:

```
select regexp_replace('JamesBond007','\d+','008');
```

results in:

```
JamesBond008
```

while

```
select regexp_replace('JamesBond007','\d*','008');
```

gives me back:

```
008JamesBond007
```

The Postgres documentation says * = a sequence of 0 or more matches of the atom.
So what is happening here? (N.B. in Oracle all the above works as expected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that `\d*` can match an empty string and you are not passing the flag `g`.

See [*`regexp_replace`*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

> The flags parameter is an optional text string containing zero or more single-letter flags that change the function's behavior. Flag `i` specifies case-insensitive matching, while **flag `g` specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one**.

The `\d*` matches the empty location at the beginning of the `JamesBond007` string, and since `g` is not passed, that empty string is replaced with `008` when you use `select regexp_replace('JamesBond007','\d*','008');` and the result is expected - `008JamesBond007`.

With `select regexp_replace('JamesBond007','\d*','');`, again, `\d*` matches the empty location at the beginning of the string, and replaces it with an empty string (no visible changes).

Note that Oracle's [*`REGEXP_REPLACE`*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) replaces all occurrences by default:

> By default, the function returns `source_char` **with every occurrence of the regular expression pattern** replaced with `replace_string`.

**In general**, you should be cautious when using patterns matching empty strings inside regex-based replace functions/methods. Do it only when you understand what you are doing. If you want to replace digit(s) you *usually* want to find at least 1 digit. Else, why remove something that is not present in the string in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Wiktor. I see how it works now. However, I still have problems to understand why Postgres needs to use these flags at all. You could specify case insensitivity within the regex itself. Also, the g flag feature could be expressed by greediness vs non-greediness of the quantifier. And why \d finds an empty location at the beginning of a string, if it should match only digits?

Comment: @absurd: Why the default behavior is different between Oracle and Postgres, I have no idea, no one asked me when implementing regexp_replace :). As for the `\d*` matching empty location at the beginning, it is totally valid since `*` means *match **zero** or more occurrences*. There are 0 digits at the beginning as the string starts with `J`. That is why it is matched.

Comment: More, flags you need to pass to the regex replace (and other regex methods) differ across languages. In .NET, `Regex.Replace` will replace all occurrences by default, in Ruby/R you need a specific function for each type of replacement (`sub` - once, `gsub` - many), in JS, you need to pass `g` flag with the regex. I think Postgres was decided to be closer to JS in some way.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Thanks again.